# Criar nova coluna no dataframe baseado em match parcial da string sem repetições

Tags: r

Eu tenho um dataframe com duas colunas, sendo elas `GL` `GLDESC` e queria adicionar uma terceira coluna chamada `KIND` baseada nos dados da coluna `GLDESC`.

Dataframe:

```
      GL                             GLDESC
1 515100                        Payroll-ISL
2 515900                        Payroll-ICA
3 532300                           Bulk Gas
4 551000                          Supply AB
5 551000                        Supply XPTO
6 551100                          Supply AB
7 551300                   Material Interno
```

Sendo que:

- Se o `GLDESC` contiver a palavra `Payroll` em qualquer lugar
  da string, `KIND` me retorna `Payroll`
- Se o `GLDESC` contiver a palavra `Supply` em qualquer lugar
  da string, `KIND` me retorna `Supply`
- Em todos os outros casos, `KIND` é `Other`.

O que é resolvido sem problemas com:

```r
DF$KIND <- ifelse(grepl("supply", DF$GLDESC, ignore.case = T), "Supply", 
         ifelse(grepl("payroll", DF$GLDESC, ignore.case = T), "Payroll", "Other"))
```

Porém, com isso, tenho tudo que cita `Supply`, por exemplo, classificado. No entanto, como nas linhas 4 e 5 do DF, o mesmo `GL` tem dois `Supply`, o que para mim é desnecessário. Na verdade, eu preciso que apenas um tipo de `GLDESC` seja classificado caso para o mesmo `GL` a string se repita.

How to?

Editado: Excluir as duplicadas não é uma saída que posso tomar. Preciso manter tudo onde está, apenas classificar o primeiro e ignorar o segundo.

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar o `grepl` para dar índices lógicos e depois calcular posições no vetor de resultados pretendidos.

```
i <- grepl("Payroll", dados$GLDESC)
j <- grepl("Supply", dados$GLDESC)
dados$KIND <- c("Other", "Payroll", "Supply")[1 + i + 2*j]

dados
#      GL           GLDESC    KIND
#1 515100      Payroll-ISL Payroll
#2 515900      Payroll-ICA Payroll
#3 532300         Bulk Gas   Other
#4 551000        Supply AB  Supply
#5 551000      Supply XPTO  Supply
#6 551100        Supply AB  Supply
#7 551300 Material Interno   Other
```

**dados.**

```
dados <- read.table(text = "
      GL                             GLDESC
1 515100                        Payroll-ISL
2 515900                        Payroll-ICA
3 532300                           'Bulk Gas'
4 551000                          'Supply AB'
5 551000                        'Supply XPTO'
6 551100                          'Supply AB'
7 551300                   'Material Interno'
", header = TRUE)
```